# Unable to install Ubuntu due to invalid acess to FAT

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ubiquity

Unable to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my HP Pavilion laptop. The Ubiquity installer gets stuck in different stages of the process, on several attempts to install Ubuntu. On the first few attempts, I got these messages:

```
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.
```

and

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
```

On later attempts, no error message would come directly, but the installer would get stuck at some stage whereon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I see an error message that says:

```
[..] fat-FS (sda1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x5e...)
```

I have tried several times using different ISO files, different versions of Ubuntu, different drive-creating software and different pen drives. I have formerly used Ubuntu on this same laptop. I have disabled Fast-bootup in Windows. The disk partitioning is GPT and Windows is running in UEFI mode.

What could be the solution?